# Indicator to the left of the Review button - Broken or hidden meaning?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I am an active contributor on the [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I perform a fair amount of volunteer moderation activities like responding to votes (but I am *not* a site moderator).

When I log into the site, directly next to the ***review*** button is a little numeric indicator that shows me how many Suggested Edits (and perhaps other things) are awaiting my review.

After I complete my reviews, the numeric indicator often decreases in value, but does not go to zero.

What am I missing?  What is that indicator indicating?  Or is it just broken?

Comment: @NathanTuggy This is indeed a duplicate of the post you found.  The answer there is not (or is no longer) accurate.  I wrote a comment under that answer.  There is now a button on the top of this post (that probably only I can see) that states "That solved my problem!".  Even though that post does not solve my problem, should I click the button anyways?

Comment: Yeah, probably. On Meta in particular, answers are less important, and questions more so; consolidating the same issue into a single spot is often the main reason for dupes. (And, of course, a new answer might be written at some point.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks! :-)  Clicking in 3...2...1...